# endianess detection and performance in C

Tags: c, endianness

I've got a performance critical C code that needs to work on a variety of platform. Some of them are little endian, others are big endian.

Detecting endianess is currently an imperfect process, based on macro detection. But it's difficult to be sure that the macro detection will work for all combinations of systems and compilers. Welcome to the world of portable code.

One relatively safe way to detect endianess is to use a runtime test, and hope that it will get optimized out by the compiler. Something along these lines :

```
static const int one = 1;
#define IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN (*(char*)(&one))
```

In general it works. The compiler should properly detect that the result of this macro is always the same for a given architecture (1 for little endian, 0 for big endian), and simply remove the memory access and associated branch altogether.

My question is : is it always the case ? Can we expect the compiler to always properly understand this test, and always optimize it correctly ? (assuming -O2/-O3 or equivalent optimization level, not applicable of course to debug code)

I'm especially worried for **bi-endian CPU**, like for example ARM. Since such CPU can be either big endian or little endian, depending on OS parameters, it might be difficult for the compiler to "hardwire" such endian test. On the other hand, I don't expect an application to work in "either endian mode of choice" : I guess it should be compiled for one precise and definitive endianess. Therefore, IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN should always result the same.

Anyway, I'm asking for experience of people having met such situation. Since I don't have a bi-endian CPU and compiler to play with currently, I'm not in position to test and observe above assumption.

[**Edit**]
@Brandin proposes to "save the result" of the macro, making it a variable. I guess he proposes something like this :

```
static const int one = 1;
static const int isLittleEndian = *(char*)(&one);
```

Since a static const int is evaluated at compile time, it would indeed guarantee that the compiler is necessarily aware of the value of isLittleEndian, and can therefore properly optimize branches which use this variable.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.
The above declaration result in the following compilation error :

```
error: initializer element is not constant
```

I guess that's because &one (a pointer address) cannot be evaluated at compile time.

@HuStmpHrrr's variant, using union instead, looks better : there is no pointer address to evaluate.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work better, and results in the same compilation error.

I guess that's because unions are not considered simple enough by the compiler to be usable as a value for a static const initialization.

So we're back to the beginning, with a macro instead.

Comment: You should strive to avoid endianness-dependent code entirely: http://commandcenter.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Comment: If you have a reliable runtime test for endianness, couldn't you perform this test exactly once when the program begins. Then the rest of the time just call your appropriate optimized functions (little endian or big endian)

Comment: Even if you can't rely on compiler optimization, you could at *least* rely on even the most trivial branch prediction.

Comment: You can simply avoid two basic things in your code: 1. Using `memcpy`/`memset`/`memcmp`,etc with operand types larger than `char`. 2. Using bit-field structures.

Comment: @barak manos Do not bit field structures have there own "bit" endianess order problem?  `struct foo { int x:1; int y:7 }`.  If `foo.x` the MSBit or LSBit?

Comment: @chux: That's exactly why I advised OP to avoid it.

Comment: @barak manos  Why yes you did, I missed the word "avoid".

Comment: @Brandin : doing the test once at the beginning of then propagating the result within the functions is what I'm doing right now. 

But it looks awkward : it requires to transmit the test result as part of all function prototypes up to the end of the chain (reading / writing data). It works, but everything looks so much more heavy now, which spells trouble for code maintenance.

I'm considering that if the test can be confined only within the last (inlined) functions (read/write data), it would be transparent for the rest of the program, and therefore make it much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Why not just save the result into `IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN` as per your original idea. You write it once and it stays the same for the program execution. It's effectively const except for first calculation

Comment: Good point @Brandin. Maybe it will help the compiler realize the result is guaranteed, and therefore the branch can be eliminated.

Comment: Not sure, maybe branch prediction helps? Best is to benchmark this after change to see if it has any affect on performance? If not then probably leave as is as there is no point in harming maintainability or worse introduce bugs

Comment: Well, as stated in the question, I can't test this situation on a bi-endian CPU. I can only test on single-endian CPU, and in such cases, it works well, as intended. So the question is really about bi-endian CPU use case, due to their capability to be, at will, either little or big endian.

Comment: @Brandin : your suggestion to "save the result" doesn't work. The result is not considered "constant" enough to be used as an initializer.

Comment: It is not an initializer because you said you dont have a reliable test outside of a runtime test. I meant you use your runtime test the first time you run it, and then cache the result in a static member variable (for example) which you will use in future decisions about endianness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same idea but different trick. this code will work too.

```
union {
  int num;
  char[sizeof(int)] bytes;
} endian;

endian.num = 1;
```

then use `endian.bytes[0]` to judge.

This way, things come more naturally and compiler should be expected to do something, since this is so easy to be tracked by a simple data flow optimizer implementation.

`endian.bytes[0]` should be shrunken down to a constant.

Anyway, this way is compiler dependent.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm aware of this version too. But my coding style convention forbids the use of union. As for any rule, there can be some justified exceptions though.
Using this version on the ground that "it should be easier for compiler to optimize" is a good enough reason, if this can be proven. Is there any example out there which proves that the pointer version is not optimized, while the union one is properly optimized ?

Comment: Why don't you benchmark the program before/after change and show how much said change increases performance.

Comment: @Cyan i am not proving, just talking about common intuitive. for c compiler, any optimization to pointer related code is convervative. for example, you have function prototype "void foo(void *a, void *b, int n)" or so, without considering the actual functionality, you are sure a and b will not be somehow related. but compiler doesn't think that way. there may be template in compiler that tells it it's a endian detecting code or not. but it's highly possible that pointer code won't be optimized.

Comment: OK, I'll use this version, on the ground that it should be easier for the compiler to guess the result.
Note however that saving the result into a static const variable doesn't work, proving that the compiler doesn't believe the result of the test to be trivial enough. But we know this kind of rule is a bit over-cautious, and the optimizer is supposed to do better in the later stages of compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the minor issue I have with the post linked inthe comment by @OliCharlesworth, I agree with its spirit: are you sure the endianness will really matter, and if it does, why?

- If it doesn't actually matter, the portable and probably very fast solution is to use `memcpy`, which will copy the bytes in host byte order. This means files won't be interchangeable between big and little endian machines.
- You can convert an integer to a specific endianness if needed as suggested in the aforementioned post by performing bit-shift operations on values regardless of endianness. For example, writing `(value >> 8) & 0xff` followed by `(value >> 0) & 0xff` to a file instead of the raw value itself will write a 16-bit value in big endian order always, and you will always read the upper 8 bits (most significant byte) of the 16-bit value first. This is essentially what functions like `htonl` do, except the value returned by the function may be different due to the possibility of the restructuring of its underlying byte representation, which is different from simply writing shifted bytes one by one.

Without more context other than "I have performance-critical code", any other guidance is unavailable. The primary issue, which I've already mentioned, is the reason why a machine's endianness is so crucial to this problem.

Comment: it could be indeed important. endian varies until some abstraction layer eliminates this difference. which means if somebody is working lower than this layer, he should take care of endian problem.

Comment: Indeed, code must be portable, and produced files must be interoperable between different machines, big and little endian.

I'm aware that writing/reading byte-by-byte would solve the issue, and btw I'm using this method in non-critical parts of the code, but it would kill performance if done within the hot loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [htonl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/byteorder.3.html) to detect it :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        if (htonl(1) == 1)
                printf("big endian\n");
        else
                printf("little endian\n");
}
```

Comment: What about optimization, which the OP specifically asked about.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour correct me if I'm wrong, but I imagine the `hton` family of functions can actually be implemented as macros, which means  `htons(1)` will simply expand to a constant.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen perhaps but the answer does not speak to it and therefore does not seem to be answering a main part of the question.

Comment: I think it answer to the part of the question that says `Can we expect the compiler to always properly understand this test, and always optimize it correctly ?`. These macros (almost on some platform) are expanded as macro depending if `__BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN`

Comment: The answer implies the references's "Network order" is the same as "big endian".  Do you have a reference to show this is always true?  I _think_ little and big are the only 2 common ones, but do other endians exist and how to test for them?

Comment: @chux http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-newman-network-byte-order-01.txt define network byte order.

Comment: Thanks. htonl() introduces some external dependency (Winsock2.h for MS Visual, but arpa/inet.h for unix, etc.). For a portable code, such dependency complexity is unwelcomed.