# How does memory(Bits) work in C Programming

Tags: c, floating-point

Please explain this paragraph:

> Floating point numbers in C use IEEE 754 encoding.
>
> This type of encoding uses a sign, a significant, and an exponent.
>
> Because of this encoding, many numbers will have small changes to allow them to be stored.
>
> Also, the number of significant digits can change slightly since it is a binary representation, not a decimal one.
>
> Single precision (float) gives you 23 bits of significant, 8 bits of exponent, and 1 sign bit.
>
> Double precision (double) gives you 52 bits of significant, 11 bits of exponent, and 1 sign bit.

I started coding in "C" recently i learned all the data structures how programs work and all.But when i saw this paragraph i didn't understand a word.

What is significant,exponent,bits.?

How does a variable,float,double store the values,how much space is required and where are they stored.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: In memory you have *sign-bit* (`0/1`) 1-bit, *normalized exponent* (`01010101`) 8-bits, and finally the *mantissa* (or significand) (`01010101010101010101010`) 23-bits that would make up the *single-precision floating point number* in memory (total 32-bits) in IEEE-754 format.

Comment: You may find [Obtaining bit representation of a float in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609743/obtaining-bit-representation-of-a-float-in-c/44611722?r=SearchResults&s=9|44.5751#44611722) helpful.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you very much for detailed explanation

Comment: The correct term for the significant bits in a floating point number is *significand*, with a *d*, not *significant*.

Comment: @Caleb My bad thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit is an "on/off" switch, encoded as 0 or 1. You can also think of it as a boolean, True or False.

The sign bit tells you if the float is positive or negitive.

The significant, also known as the Mantissa, gives you negative powers of two. For a float, you have 23 bits, so you can represent anything from 2^-23 up to 1-2^-23.

The exponent also gives you powers of 2 ranging from (2^-126,2^127).

Put everything together to get your float: (sign)(1+significant)2^(exponent)

Not all numbers can be exactly represented with powers of 2. Hence your machine approximates numbers like 0.1.

floats require 32 bits while doubles require 64 bits.

Below is a concise article on IEEE floating points which should make things clearer: https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/float/

Comment: Understood, Thanks.