# printing the bits of float

Tags: c++, floating-point, bitset, type-punning

I know. I know. This question has been answered before, but I have a slightly different and a bit more specific question.

My goal is, as the title suggest, to `cout` the `32 bits` sequence of a float.

And the solution provided in the previous questions is to use a union.

```
union ufloat{
   float f;
   uint32_t u;
};
```

This is all good and well. And I have managed to print the bits of a floating number.

```
union ufloat uf;
uf.f = numeric_limits<float>::max();
cout << bitset<32>(uf.f) << "\n"; // This give me 0x00000000, which is wrong.
cout << bitset<32>(uf.u) << "\n"; // This give me the correct bit sequence.
```

My question is why does `bitset<32>(uf.f)` doesn't work, but bitset<32>(uf.u) does?

The green-ticked anwser of this question
[Obtaining bit representation of a float in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609743/obtaining-bit-representation-of-a-float-in-c) says something about "type-punning", and I presume it's got something to do with that. But I am not sure how exactly.

Can someone please clearify? Thanks

Comment: _"...And the solution provided in the previous questions is to use a union...."_ reading the inactive member of a `union` in C++ is Undefined Behaviour. `std::memcpy` from the `float` into `uint32_t` is one way of doing what you want.

Comment: Note that C and C++ are different languages. Type punning is a way to read bytes of memory as if they were different type than they really are. This is possible to do through `union` in C, but in C++ reading anything but the last written to member of `union` is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: fwiw, some compilers do allow type punning via unions also in C++, but its nevertheless non-standard and nothing to be relied on when you want to write portable code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor of `std::bitset` you are calling is:
`constexpr bitset( unsigned long long val ) noexcept;`

When you do `bitset<32>(uf.f)`, you are converting a `float` to an `unsigned long long` value. For `numeric_limits<float>::max()`, that's undefined behavior because it's outside the range of the destination type, and in your case it happened to produce zero.

When you do `bitset<32>(uf.u)`, you are again relying on undefined behavior, and in this case it happens to do what you want: convert a `uint32_t` that contains the bits of a `float` to an `unsigned long long` value.

In C++, what you should do instead is use memcpy:

```
uint32_t u;
std::memcpy(&u, &uf.f, sizeof(u));
std::cout << std::bitset<32>(u) << "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is tagged C++, but the linked one is about C.

Those are different languages, with different rules. In particular, as mentioned in the comments by [Yksisarvinen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976805/yksisarvinen):

> Type punning is a way to read bytes of memory as if they were different type than they really are. This is possible to do through `union` in C, but in C++ reading anything but the last written to member of `union` is Undefined Behaviour.

Since C++20, we can use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast).

```
auto f{ std::numeric_limits<float>::max() };  // -> 3.40282e+38
auto u{ std::bit_cast<unsigned>(f) };         // -> 7f7fffff
```

<sup>See e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/d9T3G6qGx.</sup>